# Vue bootstrap form tags allowing duplicates

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm trying to allow duplicates in Vue bootstrap's form tags.

I've tried using `:tag-validator` (in the example) and `@tag-state` to externally modify the v-model `value`. However it seems like it is getting rid of the duplicate somewhere. Is this impossible?

Jsfiddle of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/yts54fpd/.

```html
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div>
      <b-form-group label="Tagged input using select" label-for="tags-component-select">
        <!-- Prop `add-on-change` is needed to enable adding tags vie the `change` event -->
        <b-form-tags
          :tag-validator="tagValidator"
          id="tags-component-select"
          v-model="value"
          size="lg"
          class="mb-2"
          add-on-change
          no-outer-focus
        >
          <template v-slot="{ tags, inputAttrs, inputHandlers, disabled, removeTag }">
            <ul v-if="tags.length > 0" class="list-inline d-inline-block mb-2">
              <li v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag" class="list-inline-item">
                <b-form-tag
                  @remove="removeTag(tag)"
                  :title="tag"
                  :disabled="disabled"
                  variant="info"
                >{{ tag }}</b-form-tag>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <b-form-select
              v-bind="inputAttrs"
              v-on="inputHandlers"
              :disabled="disabled"
              :options="options"
            >
              <template #first>
                <!-- This is required to prevent bugs with Safari -->
                <option disabled value="">Choose a tag...</option>
              </template>
            </b-form-select>
          </template>
        </b-form-tags>
      </b-form-group>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

```js
window.onload = () => {
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
     data() {
        return {
          options: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Lime', 'Peach', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry'],
          value: []
        }
      },
      methods: {
      tagValidator(tag) {
         this.value.push(tag)
         return true
      }
      }
  })
}
```

Comment: Any update? I am looking for a similar solution.

Comment: Nope ... at the end I created my own tag system.